# ORA-00933 when trying to compare counts

Tags: sql, oracle

This is the question

List the name of employee who work on more projects than employee 'Grace'', Show three columns in result: name of employee, project count of employee, grace's project count.

This is my code

```
SELECT employee."NAME", T1."# OF PROJECTS", 
(SELECT COUNT(pid) FROM workon WHERE empid = 30) AS "Grace's Project"
FROM employee,
(SELECT empid, COUNT(pid) AS "# OF PROJECTS"
FROM workon
GROUP BY empid
ORDER BY empid)AS T1
WHERE T1."# OF PROJECTS" > (SELECT COUNT(pid) FROM workon WHERE empid = 30)
AND t1.empid = employee.EMPID
```

I keep getting ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended. what am I missing?

Comment: Please [edit] your question title. It contains zero information now. That it's about SQL is clear by the tag you added, and *using oracle* could be replaced by just adding an Oracle tag. The fact you need help is clear by the fact you're posting here. That means that not a single word in your title is relevant. Your title should clearly describe the problem you're having or question you're asking, in a way that will be meaningful to a future user of this site when they're scanning a list of search results trying to find a solution to their problem. Your current title does not work.

Comment: question is detailed however the title may be improved

Answer (score 1):

The only error in your query is that Oracle does not accept `AS` for table aliases. Remove it and your query runs just fine.

There are two things I'd like to mention, though:

1. You are using an ancient join syntax you shouldn't use anymore. Comma-separated joins were made redundant by the introduction of explicit joins (e.g. `INNER JOIN ... ON`) in 1992.
2. Your query is a little over-complicated. Most of all, because you are counting projects thrice, once for all employees, twice for Grace. You can avoid this by using `WITH` clauses.

Here is the query built-up step by step with `WITH` clauses:

```
WITH emp AS
(
  SELECT empid, e.name, COUNT(*) AS projects
  FROM workon w
  JOIN employee e USING(empid)
  GROUP BY empid, e.name
  ORDER BY empid
)
, grace AS
(
  SELECT * FROM emp WHERE name = 'Grace'
)
SELECT 
  emp.name, 
  emp.projects as "# OF PROJECTS", 
  grace.projects as "Grace's Projects"
FROM emp
CROSS JOIN grace
WHERE emp.projects > grace.projects
ORDER BY emp.projects DESC, emp.name;
```

Demo: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=f40e2c33541c76f0af112be967370784

Answer (score 0):

I would use window functions:

```
select ew.name, ew.num_projects
from (select e.empid, e."NAME", count(*) as num_projects,
             max(case when ew."NAME" = 'Grace' then count(*) else 0 end) over () as grace_num_projects
      from employee e join
           workon w
           on w.empid = e.empid
      group by e.empid, e."NAME"
     ) ew
where num_projects > grace_num_projects;
```

Comment: it saying ew.name invalid identifier

Comment: @thermoguirand . . . Use whatever the appropriate column is for that purpose.

Comment: I tried using e.name and it's saying ORA-00937: not a single-group group function

Comment: @thermoguirand: Then you probably replaced the wrong occurrence. The error is here: `max(case when ew."NAME" ...`. Replace ew with e and the query runs fine.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
       e.empid,
      ,e."NAME"
  FROM employee e 
  INNER JOIN (SELECT
               empid
              ,count(*) as num_projects
          FROM workon  
          GROUP BY empid) w ON w.empid = e.empid
  LEFT JOIN (SELECT
             1 AS ID
             COUNT(*) as grace_projects
          FROM workon  
          GROUP BY empid
          WHERE empid = 30) g ON g.ID = 1
  WHERE w.num_projects > g.grace_projects;
```

So here's what I am doing.

I am counting the projects before they are joined, that should decrease the overhead for the query, as the return on the join is shrank considerably prior to joining.

An index on that WORKON table by EmpID would speed up the query considerably.

Then, I query Graces figures, because I want them to return a value against any person, it should only return one result for a count, and then just join that by an arbitrary value so it returns against all rows

Again, it should utilise the same index.

Because it is calculating Graces figures first, it should only need to do this once, whereas a subquery would need calculate graces figures for each employee which is an unnecessary overhead.

This is then filtered in the where clause.